# set 'dependsOn' on a Relationship field in KeystoneJS

Tags: keystonejs

I wonder if there is a way to achieve `dependsOn` option for a `Types.Relationship` field in KeystoneJS.

Example:

```
Event.add({
    category: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'EventCategory' },
    singer: { type: String, dependsOn: { category: { type: 'concerts' } } },
});
```

Currently, I can only walk around this by manually set `dependsOn` to the id of the related field.